# When I do double fork a process, is the detached process still in the same process group?

Tags: linux, process

As titled, extra question, can process group have descendants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the answer experimentally fairly easily.  I'm assuming here that by "double fork" you mean *only* double fork.  Consider the following program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("original pid/pgid: %d/%d\n", getpid(), getpgrp());

    if (fork() != 0) { return 0; }
    printf("after first fork pid/pgid: %d/%d\n", getpid(), getpgrp());

    if (fork() != 0) { return 0; }
    printf("after second fork pid/pgid: %d/%d\n", getpid(), getpgrp());

    return 0;
}
```

The program prints the process id and process group id, forks, the child prints it again, forks again, and and the child prints it again.

A sample run of the program:

```
$ ./a.out
original pid/pgid: 7306/7306
after first fork pid/pgid: 7307/7306
after second fork pid/pgid: 7308/7306
```

As you can see, the process group ID doesn't change across forks.

Comment: Thanks, can process group have children as well?

Comment: @JamesLin a process group is a collection of processes.  There are relationships among processes (e.g., parent/child), but not among process groups.

Answer (score 3):

A quick double check on google shows this from `man getpgrp`:

https://linux.die.net/man/2/getpgrp

> A child created via fork(2) inherits its parent's process group ID. The PGID is preserved across an execve(2).

In other words the process group of each child is automatically the same as its parent.  So grandchildren will, by default, share the same process group.